# AlertDialog cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android

I'm getting the following errors,i did exactly(afaik) as a guy in a tutorial but i still get the errors :
"cannot make a static reference to the non static method show() from the type dialog" at "  AlertDialog.show();"
"AlertDialog cannot be resolved or is not a field" at "AlertDialog.alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();"

Here's my code :

```
public Button paginanoua;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    paginanoua = (Button) findViewById(R.id.paginanoua);

    paginanoua.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void onClick(View view) {
    ShowDialog();
}

private void ShowDialog() {

    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialogBuilder.setTitle("Pagina noua..");
    dialogBuilder.setMessage("Sigur doriti o pagina noua?");
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Da",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Am inceput o lista noua", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }

            });
    dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Nu",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Ramanem la lista curenta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog.alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    AlertDialog.show();
}
```

What did i do wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't declare a name to your variable.

Change it with :

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Replace

```
   AlertDialog.alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
   AlertDialog.show();
```

By this

```
   AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
   alertDialog.show();
```

or just as suggested by @blackbelt

```
   dialogBuilder.show();
```

Comment: @blackbelt good one that you pointed out. dialogBuilder.show();